# How could one contact a moderator?

Tags: support, moderation

Is there a way? If using the flag (Atma assumes that such would reach one) possibility it seems that it would cause somebody to lose some of his/her reputation.

Is there a link a chat or what ever? And could there take place any communication, not like the flag possibility which seems to be limited?

Thanks for the answer(s) in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

To contact moderators privately a flag (a flag will contact any/all moderators).

Flagging a post has no automatic effect on reputation. I think you can't flag your own posts but you can flag e.g. any moderators' posts or comments.

A moderator can initiate a private chat with any user. So in your flag you can choose "in need of moderator intervention" and type a message like, "please contact me for a private chat".

Comment: Ohh, that choice did not appear when using the flag in the discussion area of a question and also has no red-10 image. That looks better and good, Sadhu!

Comment: You should have seen a message in your inbox. How about this link: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33653/private-chat-with-samana-johann

Answer (score 2):

Flagging is one way. Posting here on Meta is another way. Actually, you don't even need to contact us, one of us four should be online most of the time. We are watching most question threads and comment discussions. If there is anything you want you can just mention "moderator" in the comment text and more often than not you will be heard.

Comment: It could be something that you would not like to have the public be known about, as a moderator as well as somebody who seeks contact, Mr. Andrei Volkov. That was the reason to ask. Its btw. a good way, you do it here and avoid much underground and double work.

Comment: Sure, if it's private then yes what ChrisW said applies.

Comment: Let Atma call it discrete or careful, private (interest) is never good for a community.